# list of input checkboxes

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a list of checkboxes for timezones, something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="TimeZoneCheckbox" value="-9.00" /><label class="TimeZoneLabel">US Alaska (GMT -9:00)</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="TimeZoneCheckbox" value="-8.00" /><label class="TimeZoneLabel">US Pacific Time (GMT -8:00)</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="TimeZoneCheckbox" value="-7.00" /><label class="TimeZoneLabel">US Mountain Time (GMT -7:00)</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="TimeZoneCheckbox" value="-6.00" /><label class="TimeZoneLabel">US Central Time, Mexico City (GMT -6:00)</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="TimeZoneCheckbox" value="-5.00" /><label class="TimeZoneLabel">US Eastern Time (GMT -5:00)</label>
```

I have the following CSS:

```
.TimeZoneCheckbox{clear:left;}
.TimeZoneLabel{float:right;}
```

I'm looking to avoid using `<br />` tags and use CSS floats and clears. It should be working but it's not; what am I missing?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or this...

```
.TimeZoneCheckbox{clear:left; float: left;}
.TimeZoneLabel{float:left;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vhPT4/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.TimeZoneCheckbox{clear:left; float: left;}
.TimeZoneLabel{float:right;}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JH6MA/)

Comment: I'm looking to get the checkbox labels aligned next to the checkboxes (I'll add a margin); for the moment, they're floating to the right.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it: .TimeZoneCheckbox{clear:left;float:left;} .TimeZoneLabel{float:left;}

Comment: @frenchie ya, `float: left` for both. `clear` for `<input />`.